# How do user defined S3 Group Generic Functions work in R?

Tags: r, r-s3

I'm reading [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) and I'm confused at section [13.7.3 Group Generics](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#group-generics).

[image]

I was a bit confused by the phrasing, "...you cannot define your own group generic... defining a single group generic for your class..." but I think this section means to say that if I define the group generic `Math.MyClass` then all functions within the `Math` group generic (`abs`, `sign`, etc) will be overwritten for `MyClass` objects.

This can be confirmed by running the following:

```
my_class <- structure(.Data = -1, class = "MyClass")

my_class
# [1] -1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"

abs(my_class)
# [1] 1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"

Math.MyClass <- function(x) { x }

abs(my_class)
# [1] -1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"
```

I understand that this follows the [special naming scheme](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-basics) `generic.class` but why is the value of `.Data` affected in `abs(my_class)`?

When I created the variable `my_class`, I set the argument `.Data = -1`, and the class of -1 is `numeric` and that should not have changed:

```
class(unclass(my_class))
# [1] "numeric"

my_numeric <- unclass(my_class)

class(my_numeric)
# [1] "numeric"

abs(my_numeric)
# [1] 1
```

So why doesn't `abs(my_class)` print the same result (1) before and after I define `Math.MyClass`?

I do receive the same results before and after I define `Math.MyClass` if I define the group generic as `Math.MyClass <- function(x) {NextMethod()}` but what's the point of having group generics then?

And, why do I get the same answer for `abs(my_matrix)` both before and after I define `Math.matrix` when I run the following:

```
my_matrix <- matrix(data = -1:-10, ncol = 5) + 0.0

class(my_matrix)
# [1] "matrix"

class(my_matrix[1,1])
# [1] "numeric"

my_matrix
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   -1   -3   -5   -7   -9
# [2,]   -2   -4   -6   -8  -10

abs(my_matrix)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10

Math.matrix <- function(x) { x }

abs(my_matrix)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

And when I run the following:

```
your_class <- structure(.Data = list(-1), class = "YourClass")

your_class
# [[1]]
# [1] -1
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "YourClass"

abs(your_class)
# Error in abs(your_class) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

class(unclass(your_class))
# [1] "list"

your_list <- list(-1)

class(your_list)
# [1] "list"

abs(your_list)
# Error in abs(your_list) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

It's clear that the `class` of `.Data` does matter (initially anyway) because both `abs(your_class)` and `abs(your_list)` result in the same error.

To make things even more challenging, I found that everything goes back to normal for `MyClass` objects once I run `rm(Math.MyClass)`:

```
my_class
# [1] -1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"

abs(my_class)
# [1] -1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"

rm(Math.MyClass)

abs(my_class)
# [1] 1
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "MyClass"
```

Could someone explain more completely what group generics are (Why do group generics exist / what do they accomplish / what is their parent-child relationship with R objects / why are the `data` arguments in some objects affected when the group generic is defined and others are not / etc)?

I have more experience with OOP in Python than in R if you feel it's easier to explain with Python examples.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group generics allow you to change behavior for a group of functions for a particular data type. The best way to explain that is to look at some examples. If you run `methods("Math")` you'll see which classes have this function defined.

In the case of `Math.Date` you'll see

```
function (x, ...) 
stop(gettextf("%s not defined for \"Date\" objects", .Generic), 
    domain = NA)
```

So all that does is tell you that all these functions are not defined for Date objects. For example

```
abs(as.Date("2020-01-01"))
# Error in Math.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01")) : 
#   abs not defined for "Date" objects
```

By setting this behavior at the group level, it's not necessary to code special versions of all the functions in the Math group to tell you they are not defined for that class because they aren't numeric "in that way". But even though `trunc()` in that list and you might expect to get an error, that actually works

```
trunc(as.Date("2020-01-01"))
[1] "2020-01-01"
```

And that's because `trunc.Date` is defined.

```
function (x, ...) 
round(x - 0.4999999)
```

So the special part of group generics is that you can define a default "fallback" behavior for common math-y functions. But if you want to change that behavior, you can still provide a class specific implementation for a particular function.

Note that the same `Math.MyClass` is called for all those functions listed in the Math group. There is a variable available to the function to know which function was actually called. That variable is called `.Generic`  and is discussed on the `?UseMethod` help page. For example

```
Math.MyClass<- function(x) { paste(.Generic, x) }
abs(my_class)
# [1] "abs -1"
trunc(my_class)
# [1] "trunc -1"
exp(my_class)
# [1] "exp -1"
```

which hopefully makes it clear you don't want to directly place any transformations in there without dispatching on `.Generic`. For an example of a function that does do dispatching on some of the function types, check out `Math.difftime`

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    switch(.Generic, abs = , sign = , floor = , ceiling = , trunc = , 
        round = , signif = {
            units <- attr(x, "units")
            .difftime(NextMethod(), units)
        }, stop(gettextf("'%s' not defined for \"difftime\" objects", 
            .Generic), domain = NA))
}
```

You can see for a specific subset of functions, it will dispatch for the "normal" implementations, otherwise it throws an error.

So when you defined

```
Math.MyClass <- function(x) { x }
```

Basically you told R that you would handle the call to `abs()` for objects of that class. And when you returned `x` unchanged in your implementation, you basically just returned the same object and did nothing. When you don't define `Math.MyClass`, then R goes through the "normal" steps to determine how to call the function. Since you didn't provide a custom "identity" function, it falls back to the default numeric behavior.

As for why the `matrix` behavior didn't change, that's because the class of `my_matrix` is determined implicitly. If you do dump the object, you'll see

```
dput(my_matrix)
# structure(
#     c(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10), 
#     .Dim = c(2L, 5L))
```

Note that it's not storing the class in the object itself like your `my_class` object

```
dput(my_class)
# structure(-1, class = "MyClass")
```

With the implicit classes, dispatching happens a bit differently and it's dispatch more like the extra class isn't there. The class based dispatch checks for that `class` attribute on the object. Note that this will behave differently

```
my_matrix2 <- structure(my_matrix, class="matrix")
# abs(my_matrix2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   -1   -3   -5   -7   -9
# [2,]   -2   -4   -6   -8  -10
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "matrix"
```

You can see that in this case `Math.matrix` is called and nothing is changed.